# No backends assigned to my Account

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

[image]When I open my account on IBM Quantum Experience, I am shown 9 backends that are assigned to me. But when I open any of my circuits, I get the error that "This account has no backends assigned". This is a rather new problem, as I was able to access backends before but now I am unable to run my circuits anymore.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your specific case: If you ask some mysterious problem, in general helps a lot if you illustrate it, like copy-paste the exact error message or give some screenshots.

Comment: Make sure you use the correct "hub", "group" and "project" setting.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because server issues should not concern this SE.

Answer (score 0):

[image: This my quantum experience screen.]

This is my quantum experience screen for past hour. No matter which circuit I open, I get the same error and "Loading" where Run settings and backends should be.

Comment: Someone else reported a similar issue on Slack, and according to the IQX admin they've found and fixed the issue, if you want to try again.

Comment: Thank you, I just checked and it works!